# How can I install python-Orange on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python-2.7

```
sudo apt-get install python-Orange
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python-orange
```

doesn't work

```
sudo python setup.py install
sudo python setup.py build
```

is not working as well.

Can anyone help??

Comment: http://orange.biolab.si/svn/orange/trunk/orange/doc/INSTALL.linux.txt , and no, it's not in the Ubuntu repository

Answer (score 2):

Python has two tools for easy installation of all programs that are listed on the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), also known as PyPi:  These are easy_install and pip.  Both retrieve very recent versions of Orange (and of any other package that is updating its PyPi entry regularly).

I installed Orange on Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) with
`pip install orange`.
You will see lots of log lines indicating that Pip is downloading and compiling Orange for you.  Simply wait.  When pip is ready, fire up python and try to `import orange`.  If that works, quit python and try the GUI with `python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Orange/OrangeCanvas/orngCanvas.pyw` (you probably want to create a shell alias or bash script for that one  :-)

NOTE: on 12.04 I needed to first upgrade 'distribute' itself with `sudo easy_install -U distribute` but this was clearly indicated by pip.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange/2.6/

You need to extract the dowloaded tarball on that page to a folder and then change directory to that folder. Then the **sudo python setup.py...** instructions will work (but you should 'build' the application before you 'install' it).

Answer (score 0):

go to the given link "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange/2.6/"
download the package and extract the file 
install with given command

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

note:- during installation make sure that your net is working because it downloads required packages. Also it may ask for C++ or gcc compilers while installing and could be terminate just read the errors care fully and install requires packages from the synaptic package manage in ubuntu.