# Unable to compile / install Orange Data Mining on Raspberry Pi

Tags: orange

I have been trying to compile and install Orange 2.7.8 on Raspberry Pi 2 but was unsuccessful. I tried compiling by hand and also used `pip install orange` as per suggestion from: [How can I install python-Orange on ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024191/how-can-i-install-python-orange-on-ubuntu-12-10)

The first warning I got this:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/include -Isource/include -Isource/orange/liblinear -Isource/orange/ppp -Isource/orange/px -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c source/orange/basstat.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/source/orange/basstat.o -fPIC -w -DLINUX -DORANGE_EXPORTS

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
```

But it kept going without an error. Then when it started compiling with g++, it started getting an error on multiple definition of TOrangeVector. There are many errors like the lines below:

```
build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/source/orange/distance.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x6c): multiple definition of `typeinfo for TOrangeVector<GCPtr<TVariable>, true>'

build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/source/orange/basstat.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x6c): first defined here

build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/source/orange/distance.o: In function `TExamplesDistance::classDescription() const':

/home/pi/build/orange/source/orange/ppp/distance.ppp:17: multiple definition of `typeinfo for TOrangeVector<bool, false>'
```

In the end it got kicked out:

```
/home/pi/build/orange/source/orange/vectortemplates.hpp:1075: multiple definition of `typeinfo name for TOrangeVector<GCPtr<TOrangeVector<GCPtr<TVariable>, true> >, true>'

build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/source/orange/basstat.o:/home/pi/build/orange/source/orange/ppp/../basstat.hpp:8: first defined here

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Any guide on how to tweak this to make it compiled would be appreciated.